# Solving the biharmonic equation in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pde

I am attempting to solve the linear biharmonic equation in mathematica using DSolve. I think this issue is not just limited to the biharmonic equation but MATHEMATICA just spits out the equation when I attempt to solve it.

I've tried solving other partial differential equations and there was no trouble.

### The biharmonic equation is just:

```
Laplacian^2[f]=0
```

### Here is my equation:

```
DSolve[
 D[f[x, y], {x, 4}] + 2 D[D[f[x, y], {x, 2}, {y, 2}]] + 
   D[f[x, y], {y, 4}] == 0,
 f,
 {x, y}]
```

### The solution is spit out as

```
DSolve[(f^(0,4))[x,y]+2 (f^(2,2))[x,y]+(f^(4,0))[x,y]==0,f,{x,y}]
```

That is obviously not the solution. What gives? What am I missing? I've solved other PDEs without boundary conditions.

Comment: According to the documentation of `DSolve`, the function can "solve many linear equations up to second order with nonconstant coefficients". So my guess is that `DSolve` fails because the biharmonic equation is a fourth order PDE.

Comment: @Heike Looks to be the case. How am I to solve this equation in mathematica? I have solved fourth order non-linear pdes before, but with NDSolve...

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiharmonicEquation.html

Comment: Shouldn't your second term be `D[f[x, y], {x, 2}, {y, 2}]` or `D[D[f[x, y], {x, 2}], {y, 2}]`?

Comment: See also http://www.ekayasolutions.com/UCDMath/PapkovitchEigenFunctions.nb

Comment: @belisarius Yes, I did check that previously. Although they don't really attempt at solving it through DSolve.

Comment: @MengLu Hmmm... well what do you know? It didn't make much of a difference, mathematica still just spits my equation back at me...

Comment: I had a meeting with a math faculty and I realized that the biharmonic equation (cartesian) doesn't probably have an analytical solution. There is some substitution and separation of variables involved which MATHEMATICA doesn't quite figure out on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about try it in polar coordinates? If `f(r, \[Theta])` is symmetric with respect to azimuth `\[Theta]`, the biharmonic equation reduces to something Mathematca can solve symbolically (c.f. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiharmonicEquation.html):

```
In[22]:= eq = D[r D[D[r D[f[r],r],r]/r,r],r]/r;
eq//FullSimplify//TraditionalForm

Out[23]//TraditionalForm= f^(4)(r) + (2 r^2 f^(3)(r) - r f''(r)
                           + f'(r))/r^3

In[24]:= DSolve[eq==0,f,r]
Out[24]= {{f -> Function[{r}, 
                 1/2 r^2 C[2] - 1/4 r^2 C[3] + C[4] + C[1] Log[r] 
                   + 1/2 r^2 C[3] Log[r]
                ]}}

In[25]:= ReplaceAll[
    1/2 r^2 C[2]-1/4 r^2 C[3]+C[4]+C[1] Log[r]+1/2 r^2 C[3] Log[r],
    r->Sqrt[x^2+y^2]
]
Out[25]= 1/2 (x^2+y^2) C[2]-1/4 (x^2+y^2) C[3]+C[4]+C[1] Log[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]]+ 
1/2 (x^2+y^2) C[3] Log[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]]
```

Comment: This helps a lot! Thanks! :) however, I'd love to be able to do it in cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

DSolve[D[f[x, y], {x, 4}] + 2 D[f[x, y], {x, 2}, {y, 2}] +
D[f[x, y], {y, 4}] == 0, f, {x, y}]

This ought to be the actual syntax

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).